# How to select values except the hidden values from the "Select" tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I am trying to select all the values from the form except the values which are hidden. But event after using `input:not([type='hidden']),select,textarea` it selects all values from `select` tag which has hidden value.

Function called when submit button is pressed:

```
function getInfoSectionValues($objSection) {
    var objValue = {};
    $objSection.find(".info, .info-container").find("input:not([type='hidden']),select,textarea").each(function () {
        let strKey = ($(this).attr('data-apiname') !== undefined) ? $(this).attr("data-apiname") : $(this).attr("class");
        objValue[strKey] = $(this).val();
    });
    return objValue;
}



<select class="form-control origin" data-apiname= "Origin" id="originId" placeholder="Test1" required="required">
    <option value="" class="hidden">Test1</option>
    <repeating the values here passed from the server>
</select>
```

Actual :

```
Form1: "Pharmacy"
Origin: "Choose Case Origin"
Priority: "Medium"
Status: "Open"
SubStatus: ""
SubStatusReason: ""
Subject: "
```

Expected :

```
Form1: "Pharmacy"
Origin: ""
Priority: "Medium"
Status: "Open"
SubStatus: ""
SubStatusReason: ""
Subject: "
```

Comment: You're using `class="hidden"`, so your selector should be `option:not(.hidden)`

Comment: `input[type=hidden]` selector has nothing to do with `<option>` or `<select>`. It is for `<input type="hidden">`. Also if you are trying to hide `<option>` it does not work cross browser. Choices are remove/replace or disable/enable

Answer (score 0):

To filter out a `<select>` that has an option with a class `hidden` use :

```
.find("select:not(:has(.hidden)),textarea")
```

The selector `input:not([type='hidden'])` is for `<input>` elements that are not `<input type="hidden">`

Since no html was provided and a weak explanation ... this is the best interpretation available of the problem

Comment: There are many input and select tags in the form this I tried using the solution like below : `$objSection.find(".info, .info-container").find("input:not([type='hidden']),select:not(:has(.hidden)),select,textarea").each(function () {})` but this does not work.

Comment: Then you need to provide a [mcve]. *"does not work"* is almost meaningless